# Apply a condition to a group when condition is only on one row

Tags: r

I have this data set as follows

```
structure(list(count = c("0-0", "1-0", "2-0", "2-1", "0-0", "0-1", 
"0-2", "1-2", "1-2", "0-0", "0-1", "1-1", "1-2", "2-2", "2-2", 
"0-0", "1-0", "1-1", "2-1", "3-1", "3-2", "0-0", "1-0", "1-1", 
"0-0", "0-1", "1-1", "1-2", "0-0", "1-0", "1-1", "0-0", "0-1", 
"0-0", "1-0", "1-1", "1-2", "0-0", "0-1", "0-2", "0-0", "0-1", 
"0-2", "1-2", "1-2", "0-0", "0-0", "0-1", "0-0", "0-0", "0-0", 
"1-0", "2-0", "0-0", "1-0", "2-0", "3-0", "0-0", "0-0", "1-0", 
"1-1", "0-0", "0-0", "1-0", "2-0", "0-0", "0-1", "0-2", "0-2", 
"0-0", "1-0", "1-1", "2-1", "2-2", "2-2", "0-0", "1-0", "2-0", 
"2-1", "2-2", "0-0", "0-1", "0-0", "0-0", "0-1", "0-2", "0-2", 
"1-2", "2-2", "0-0", "1-0", "1-1", "0-0", "1-0", "0-0", "0-1", 
"1-1", "1-2"), pitchResult = c("Ball", "Ball", 
"Foul", "Ground Out", "Foul", "Strike Looking", "Ball", "Foul", 
"Ground Out", "Strike Looking", "Ball", "Foul", "Ball", "Foul", 
"Ground Out", "Ball", "Strike Looking", "Ball", "Ball", "Strike Swinging", 
"Single on a Fly Ball", "Ball", "Strike Swinging", "Double Play", 
"Strike Looking", "Ball", "Strike Looking", "Ground Out", "Ball", 
"Strike Swinging", "Ground Out", "Foul", "Single on a Fly Ball", 
"Ball", "Strike Swinging", "Strike Swinging", "Strikeout (Swinging)", 
"Strike Looking", "Foul", "Strikeout (Swinging)", "Strike Looking", 
"Strike Looking", "Ball", "Foul", "Fly Out", "Fly Out", "Strike Looking", 
"Fly Out", "Double on a Fly Ball", "Hit By Pitch", "Ball", "Ball", 
"Fly Out", "Ball", "Ball", "Ball", "Walk", "Double Play", "Ball", 
"Strike Looking", "Single on a Ground Ball", "Fly Out", "Ball", 
"Ball", "Fly Out", "Strike Looking", "Foul", "Foul", "Single on a Ground Ball", 
"Ball", "Strike Looking", "Ball", "Foul", "Foul", "Home Run on a 402.65 ft Fly Ball", 
"Ball", "Ball", "Strike Swinging", "Foul", "Fly Out", "Strike Swinging", 
"Line Out", "Fly Out", "Strike Looking", "Foul", "Foul", "Ball", 
"Ball", "Single on a Ground Ball", "Ball", "Strike Looking", 
"Fielder's Choice", "Ball", "Ground Out", "Foul", "Ball", "Strike Swinging", 
"Single on a Line Drive"), gameId = c(536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 536158720L, 
536158720L), inn = c("Top 1", "Top 1", 
"Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", 
"Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 1", "Top 2", 
"Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", 
"Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 2", "Top 3", "Top 3", 
"Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 3", 
"Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 3", "Top 4", "Top 4", "Top 4", "Top 4", 
"Top 4", "Top 4", "Top 4", "Top 4", "Top 5", "Top 5", "Top 5", 
"Top 5", "Top 5", "Top 5", "Top 5", "Top 5", "Top 5", "Top 5", 
"Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", 
"Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", 
"Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", "Top 6", 
"Top 6", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", 
"Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 7", "Top 8", 
"Top 8", "Top 8", "Top 8", "Top 8", "Top 8"
), batter = c("Player A", "Player A", "Player A", "Player A", "Player B", "Player B", 
"Player B", "Player B", "Player B", "Player C", "Player C", "Player C", "Player C", 
"Player C", "Player C", "Player D", "Player D", "Player D", "Player D", "Player D", 
"Player D", "Player E", "Player E", "Player E", "Player F", "Player F", "Player F", 
"Player F", "Player G", "Player G", "Player G", "Player H", "Player H", "Player I", 
"Player I", "Player I", "Player I", "Player A", "Player A", "Player A", "Player B", 
"Player B", "Player B", "Player B", "Player B", "Player C", "Player D", "Player D", 
"Player E", "Player F", "Player G", "Player G", "Player G", "Player H", "Player H", 
"Player H", "Player H", "Player I", "Player A", "Player A", "Player A", "Player B", 
"Player C", "Player C", "Player C", "Player D", "Player D", "Player D", "Player D", 
"Player E", "Player E", "BPlayer E", "Player E", "Player E", "Player E", "Player F", "Player F", 
"Player F", "Player F", "Player F", "Player G", "Player G", "Player H", "Player I", 
"Player I", "Player I", "Player I", "Player I", "Player I", "Player A", "Player A", "Player A", 
"Player B", "Player B", "Player C", "Player C", "Player C", "Player C"), pitcher = c("Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", "Player 1", 
"Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", 
"Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", 
"Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2", "Player 2"
), bb = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Where Players A-I take at bats (groups of pitches) against Player 1 and 2... If Player A Walked or got Hit by the pitch in their at bat it is denoted in the bb column on the pitch where that event occurred. What I want to do is have that bb column show a 1 for the entire at bat if they were walked or hit by the pitch instead of just on the row where the event happened.

Comment: Based on your shown data, how does your expected output look like? What do you mean with _for the entire at bat_ ?

Comment: The output would have the 'bb' column show 1 if at the end of the at bat had a walk/hit by pitch denoted by the 1 in the 'bb' column in this data set.

Comment: @MartinGal The entire at bat would be the rows that have the same batter in a row, so the first 'at bat' would be four rows as player A appears four times in a row, and then the next at bat would begin which would be five rows as player B appears five times in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar approach like Abdur Rohman but with slightly different interpretation of your description:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df[1:98,] %>% 
  group_by(batter, grp = cumsum(coalesce(batter != lag(batter), FALSE))) %>% 
  mutate(new_bb = +any(str_detect(pitchResult, "Walk|Hit"))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 98 x 8
   count pitchResult                         gameId inn   batter    pitcher     bb new_bb
   <chr> <chr>                                <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>  <int>
 1 0-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 1 Player A  Player 1     0      0
 2 1-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 1 Player A  Player 1     0      0
 3 2-0   Foul                             536158720 Top 1 Player A  Player 1     0      0
 4 2-1   Ground Out                       536158720 Top 1 Player A  Player 1     0      0
 5 0-0   Foul                             536158720 Top 1 Player B  Player 1     0      0
 6 0-1   Strike Looking                   536158720 Top 1 Player B  Player 1     0      0
 7 0-2   Ball                             536158720 Top 1 Player B  Player 1     0      0
 8 1-2   Foul                             536158720 Top 1 Player B  Player 1     0      0
 9 1-2   Ground Out                       536158720 Top 1 Player B  Player 1     0      0
10 0-0   Strike Looking                   536158720 Top 1 Player C  Player 1     0      0
...
48 0-1   Fly Out                          536158720 Top 4 Player D  Player 1     0      0
49 0-0   Double on a Fly Ball             536158720 Top 5 Player E  Player 1     0      0
50 0-0   Hit By Pitch                     536158720 Top 5 Player F  Player 1     1      1
51 0-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 5 Player G  Player 1     0      0
52 1-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 5 Player G  Player 1     0      0
53 2-0   Fly Out                          536158720 Top 5 Player G  Player 1     0      0
54 0-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 5 Player H  Player 1     0      1
55 1-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 5 Player H  Player 1     0      1
56 2-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 5 Player H  Player 1     0      1
57 3-0   Walk                             536158720 Top 5 Player H  Player 1     1      1
58 0-0   Double Play                      536158720 Top 5 Player I  Player 1     0      0
59 0-0   Ball                             536158720 Top 6 Player A  Player 1     0      0
...
95 0-0   Foul                             536158720 Top 8 Player C  Player 2     0      0
96 0-1   Ball                             536158720 Top 8 Player C  Player 2     0      0
97 1-1   Strike Swinging                  536158720 Top 8 Player C  Player 2     0      0
98 1-2   Single on a Line Drive           536158720 Top 8 Player C  Player 2     0      0
```

I don't know if the last batter of an inn (whatever this means) can be the new first batter of a new inn. In this case you need to include `inn` in the `group_by` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with baseball rules, but I tried to get the result that matches your description. Note that I found your data has 100 rows, but the 98th row and the 99th row are "NA" so I just use row 1 to row 98. Here is my trial:

```
dat[1:98,] %>% 
   group_by(batter, inn) %>% 
   mutate(wanted_bb = ifelse(any(bb ==1) & str_detect(pitchResult, "[Walk|Hit]"), 1, 0)) %>% 
   select(-bb) %>% 
   as.data.frame()
```

The result:

```
count                      pitchResult    gameId   inn    batter  pitcher wanted_bb
1    0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 1  Player A Player 1         0
2    1-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 1  Player A Player 1         0
3    2-0                             Foul 536158720 Top 1  Player A Player 1         0
4    2-1                       Ground Out 536158720 Top 1  Player A Player 1         0
5    0-0                             Foul 536158720 Top 1  Player B Player 1         0
6    0-1                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 1  Player B Player 1         0
7    0-2                             Ball 536158720 Top 1  Player B Player 1         0
8    1-2                             Foul 536158720 Top 1  Player B Player 1         0
9    1-2                       Ground Out 536158720 Top 1  Player B Player 1         0
10   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 1  Player C Player 1         0
11   0-1                             Ball 536158720 Top 1  Player C Player 1         0
12   1-1                             Foul 536158720 Top 1  Player C Player 1         0
13   1-2                             Ball 536158720 Top 1  Player C Player 1         0
14   2-2                             Foul 536158720 Top 1  Player C Player 1         0
15   2-2                       Ground Out 536158720 Top 1  Player C Player 1         0
16   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 2  Player D Player 1         0
17   1-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 2  Player D Player 1         0
18   1-1                             Ball 536158720 Top 2  Player D Player 1         0
19   2-1                             Ball 536158720 Top 2  Player D Player 1         0
20   3-1                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 2  Player D Player 1         0
21   3-2             Single on a Fly Ball 536158720 Top 2  Player D Player 1         0
22   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 2  Player E Player 1         0
23   1-0                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 2  Player E Player 1         0
24   1-1                      Double Play 536158720 Top 2  Player E Player 1         0
25   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 2  Player F Player 1         0
26   0-1                             Ball 536158720 Top 2  Player F Player 1         0
27   1-1                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 2  Player F Player 1         0
28   1-2                       Ground Out 536158720 Top 2  Player F Player 1         0
29   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 3  Player G Player 1         0
30   1-0                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 3  Player G Player 1         0
31   1-1                       Ground Out 536158720 Top 3  Player G Player 1         0
32   0-0                             Foul 536158720 Top 3  Player H Player 1         0
33   0-1             Single on a Fly Ball 536158720 Top 3  Player H Player 1         0
34   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 3  Player I Player 1         0
35   1-0                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 3  Player I Player 1         0
36   1-1                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 3  Player I Player 1         0
37   1-2             Strikeout (Swinging) 536158720 Top 3  Player I Player 1         0
38   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 3  Player A Player 1         0
39   0-1                             Foul 536158720 Top 3  Player A Player 1         0
40   0-2             Strikeout (Swinging) 536158720 Top 3  Player A Player 1         0
41   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 4  Player B Player 1         0
42   0-1                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 4  Player B Player 1         0
43   0-2                             Ball 536158720 Top 4  Player B Player 1         0
44   1-2                             Foul 536158720 Top 4  Player B Player 1         0
45   1-2                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 4  Player B Player 1         0
46   0-0                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 4  Player C Player 1         0
47   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 4  Player D Player 1         0
48   0-1                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 4  Player D Player 1         0
49   0-0             Double on a Fly Ball 536158720 Top 5  Player E Player 1         0
50   0-0                     Hit By Pitch 536158720 Top 5  Player F Player 1         1
51   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 5  Player G Player 1         0
52   1-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 5  Player G Player 1         0
53   2-0                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 5  Player G Player 1         0
54   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 5  Player H Player 1         1
55   1-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 5  Player H Player 1         1
56   2-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 5  Player H Player 1         1
57   3-0                             Walk 536158720 Top 5  Player H Player 1         1
58   0-0                      Double Play 536158720 Top 5  Player I Player 1         0
59   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player A Player 1         0
60   1-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 6  Player A Player 1         0
61   1-1          Single on a Ground Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player A Player 1         0
62   0-0                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 6  Player B Player 1         0
63   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player C Player 1         0
64   1-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player C Player 1         0
65   2-0                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 6  Player C Player 1         0
66   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 6  Player D Player 1         0
67   0-1                             Foul 536158720 Top 6  Player D Player 1         0
68   0-2                             Foul 536158720 Top 6  Player D Player 1         0
69   0-2          Single on a Ground Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player D Player 1         0
70   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player E Player 1         0
71   1-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 6  Player E Player 1         0
72   1-1                             Ball 536158720 Top 6 BPlayer E Player 1         0
73   2-1                             Foul 536158720 Top 6  Player E Player 1         0
74   2-2                             Foul 536158720 Top 6  Player E Player 1         0
75   2-2 Home Run on a 402.65 ft Fly Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player E Player 1         0
76   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player F Player 1         0
77   1-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 6  Player F Player 1         0
78   2-0                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 6  Player F Player 1         0
79   2-1                             Foul 536158720 Top 6  Player F Player 1         0
80   2-2                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 6  Player F Player 1         0
81   0-0                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 7  Player G Player 1         0
82   0-1                         Line Out 536158720 Top 7  Player G Player 1         0
83   0-0                          Fly Out 536158720 Top 7  Player H Player 2         0
84   0-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 7  Player I Player 2         0
85   0-1                             Foul 536158720 Top 7  Player I Player 2         0
86   0-2                             Foul 536158720 Top 7  Player I Player 2         0
87   0-2                             Ball 536158720 Top 7  Player I Player 2         0
88   1-2                             Ball 536158720 Top 7  Player I Player 2         0
89   2-2          Single on a Ground Ball 536158720 Top 7  Player I Player 2         0
90   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 7  Player A Player 2         0
91   1-0                   Strike Looking 536158720 Top 7  Player A Player 2         0
92   1-1                 Fielder's Choice 536158720 Top 7  Player A Player 2         0
93   0-0                             Ball 536158720 Top 8  Player B Player 2         0
94   1-0                       Ground Out 536158720 Top 8  Player B Player 2         0
95   0-0                             Foul 536158720 Top 8  Player C Player 2         0
96   0-1                             Ball 536158720 Top 8  Player C Player 2         0
97   1-1                  Strike Swinging 536158720 Top 8  Player C Player 2         0
98   1-2           Single on a Line Drive 536158720 Top 8  Player C Player 2         0
```